# how can I run a webRTc demo in two different pc

Tags: webrtc

I am trying to learn webRTC from [webRTC Google Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#0)
 They have given a lot of demo projects.Almost all of them run perfectly http://127.0.0.1:8887 only in the same pc.
But how do I run a demo on two different pc? 
 Do I need to do something more to run these on two different pc? then what should I do?
 Can you suggest any tutorials for this work?

Comment: Well put the page on a webserver and access it from different computers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run your server on the private IP of your local network. Make sure your two machines are sharing the same network.

**Step 1 Find the private IP.**

On windows: type `ipconfig` in the command line prompt.
On Linux: type `ifconfig` in the terminal.

**Step 2 Self-sign SSL to your local server**

Http will only work when running WebRTC on the non-localhost environment. Since you will be running the server on a private IP, you need to self-sign the server with a fake certificate.

**Step 3 Run server on your private IP address.**

Configure your application server to run on the private IP address

Yay, you can now connect start your WebRTC session via the private IP address.